# Real World Application using Smart Contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-design, dapp-development

I am trying to build an application using Smart Contracts. I am only able to find tutorials that introduce Solidity and smart contracts (which are helpful though). But I am unable to find a complete explanation of a real world application using Ethereum.

I understand that no one would want to share their business logic but code for Verified Smart Contracts is available on etherscan.io. So if there is any available explanation to a fully deployed application (anything other than DeFi), please  guide me to it.

Else, consider an example: APPII (appii.io) - a website which facilitates employers find verified job applicants. Please try to answer the following (read as - how it could have been built):

1. What could one of their transactions contain? (In the case of storing personal details, will they store all data as stored in a spreadsheet or just a hash of the data?)
2. Is any information verified by the nodes? (In the case of crypto transactions, there is a checklist after which the transaction is added to the mempool. So, is there anything like that for non-crypto transactions?)

Please add anything else that you think would be useful. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to give [Hardhat's Hackathon Boilerplate](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/hackathon-boilerplate-project.html) a try. It goes over the entire DApp development life-cycle, while keeping things simple enough to digest. It includes a starter code for both the Ethereum backend (Solidity), and the web3 front-end (React).